# Struggling with streamlining javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I always find myself copy and pasting the same function over and over again. I have tons of trouble understanding how to write more flexible code.

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave','#claps10',function () {
    "use strict";
    if ($(window).width() > 800) {
        $('.inco10').stop().animate({width: 'toggle', height: '125px'});
    }
});

$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave','#claps11',function () {
    "use strict";
    if ($(window).width() > 800) {
        $('.inco11').stop().animate({width: 'toggle', height: '125px'});
    }
});
```

I have 11 of those when I know there is a better way to have just one. I just am not skilled enough to do it. What do you call that and can you show me a sample of how this can be done?

Comment: Identify what's variable (the selector(s)) and create a function that contains the logic and accepts the variable values as arguments. There could be other ways depending on the relationship of the DOM elements in the document or the regularity of your IDs/class names, but that's the generic approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all elements having id starting with `claps` using `[id^=claps]` selector, then get the id of the target element using `$(this)` (`claps11` for example) remove `claps` from the id using `$(this).attr("id").replace("claps", "")` to get the number (11) then concatenate it with the class.

```
  $(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave','[id^=claps]',function () {
        "use strict";

        var idNumber = $(this).attr("id").replace("claps", "");
        if ($(window).width() > 800) {
            $('.inco'+idNumber).stop().animate({width: 'toggle', height: '125px'});
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is amazing that this works! Thank you! How do you know how to do this. What can I look up to understand how to always write code this way?

Comment: Always think of writing a general solution.. you do not need to replicate bits of code here and there. There is always a way to combine logic in one place but this requires a bit of extra knowledge with the technology you are using as well as experience. StackOverflow is a great place to boost your knowledge and learn good code practices from peers. Just keep yourself updated.

Comment: @riotgear: It's quite similar to what I wrote in my comment in your question. Identify the parts that are fixed and the ones that are variable. E.g. all element IDs start with "claps", only the number is different. So the first question is, is it possible to select all elements whose ID start with "claps"? (yes) Then given a DOM element (`this`), is it possible to extract the variable part from ID (the number) from it? (yes) What's the fixed part of the second selector? (`'.inco'`) Is it possible to build a selector from the fixed part + the selected number? (yes) etc...

Comment: FWIW, `$(this).attr("id")` can be simplified to `this.id`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to acheive this :

Use class name for mouseenter and mouseleave

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave','.claps',function () {
"use strict";
   logicFunction(this.id.replace("claps", "inco");
});
function logicFunction(className)
{

   if ($(window).width() > 800) {
       $('.'+className).stop().animate({width: 'toggle', height: '125px'});
   }
}
```